# Recording issue in recorder.js for mp3

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, audio-recording

I'm facing issue in making mp3 format audio and storing it on server. When recording audio, the resulting recording is approximately twice as long as what was recorded, and the extra space is blank.

Example. Recorded 18 second audio clip. The first 18 seconds are the audio, and the actual length of the recording is 36 seconds. The last 18 seconds are blank.

It's working fine if I use wav format. Tried to locate the issue but I'm unable to find.

```
$(document).on("click", ".save", function () {
    function upload(blob) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var photoId = $('#photoId').val();
        formData.append('file', blob);
        formData.append('photoId', photoId);
        var url = base_url + '/uploadAudio';
        var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (resp) {

            }
        });
    }
    if ($(this).parent().data("type") === "mp3") {
        Fr.voice.exportMP3(upload, "blob");
    } else {
        Fr.voice.export(upload, "blob");
    }
    restore();
});
```

Js library used is: [Fr.voice](http://subinsb.com/html5-record-mic-voice/#export-mp3)

Comment: What is `Fr.voice`?

Comment: @Richard this is js library for Fr.voice http://subinsb.com/html5-record-mic-voice/

Comment: 1. That information should be clearly in the question. 2. using abandonware has its risks.

Comment: 1- added.
2- but I tried to find any other plugin/library but didn't. If you can refer any other I'll try that. This issue has taken a week of me.